# How do I select all documents that creation date equal or less than the today?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I would like to select all documents that the creation date equal or less than the actual date(Today), how do i go about this.I have a view selection formula

```
@Select Form="Memo" & @Adjust(@Created; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0)<= @Today
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close:

```
@Select Form="Memo" & @Date(@Created) <= @Today
```

The problem is, though, that ALL documents will ALWAYS have been created today or earlier. :)

Perhaps you want all documents that were created prior to a certain date?

```
@Select Form="Memo" & @Date(@Created) <= @Date(2016, 7, 7)
```

Comment: Please note: using @Today in select formulas can have heavy performance impacts, as the view index needs to constantly recalc. You can read more about it [here](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-92JFE4)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to have an agent that runs daily to set a field on the document and then use that field in your view selection formula.

like

```
ScheduledAgentThatRunsAtMidnight

Sub Initialize
.
.
doc.ThisDocWasCreatedBeforeToday = "Y"
. 
.
```

and

```
ThisDocWasCreatedBeforeToday = "Y"
```

as the selection formula.